# How do I format a string with string interpolation in Scala as a fixed width string?

Tags: scala, padding, scala-2.10, string-interpolation, format-string

I'm interfacing with a really old system and the file I need to generate needs a field that is a formed from a string but needs to be exactly 15 in width.

I want something like this:

```
val companyName = "FooBar, Inc" // 11 chars
f"$companyName%s"
```

To return:

```
"    FooBar, Inc"
```

Is there a slick way to do what I'm trying to do with the String interpolation?

Comment: This question now seems really simple, this is because I was doing something else wrong when I had the solution the whole time, so I striped down the question so it made sense.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) with a [format string](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). Surely something there will do what you want :-)

This code would do what you want:

```
scala> val companyName = "FooBar, Inc"
companyName: String = FooBar, Inc

scala> f"$companyName%15s"
res0: String = "    FooBar, Inc"
```

Comment: Oh, wow. I'm going to edit my question since it's not even correct.  I don't know what I was typing into the REPL since this does clearly work. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to get left-aligned formatting (padding spaces on the right hand side) with this approach?

Comment: Yes, pre-pend '-' to the width specifier:

`scala> f"$companyName%-15s"`

Comment: can I make the 15 a parameter: like `val w=15` and now do something like: `f"$companyName%${w}s"`

Comment: @drjerry Probably the only way of achieving something like this is using `String.format("%" + w + "s", w, companyName)`.